# arbitrary Angular template string without templateRef

Tags: angular, typescript

is there a way to pass a string that received from an external resource (i.e http response) as a dynamic template that binds to the component's instance without using templatwRef?

**details**
say we have AppComponent that has 9nlt one variable `name` and doesn't have a corresponding static template, i.e the html part doesn't exist in the code base, instead it will obtained at the runtime from an external source.

it should be injected and acts like any normal template, that has an access to the prop `name`

```
httpClient.get('template').then(val=>{
// val: '<div> {{name}} </div>'
  this.template = val;
})
```

Comment: yes. there is....

Comment: how? @E.Maggini

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you want you'll need to compile the template. That's where things are getting a bit more complicated.

Which would look like that :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: '<div #container></div>',
})
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false })
  container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Define the component using Component decorator.
    const component = Component({
      selector: 'test',
      template: '<div>This is the dynamic template. Test value: {{test}}</div>',
      styles: [':host {color: red}'],
    })(
      class {
        test = 'some value';
      }
    );

    // Define the module using NgModule decorator.
    const module = NgModule({ declarations: [component] })(class {});

    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(component, {
      injector: this.injector,
      ngModuleRef: createNgModuleRef(module, this.injector),
    });
    setTimeout(() => (componentRef.instance.test = 'some other value'), 2000);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qexlu4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: you just loaded a component into another one, this is not what I ask for. I just want to get the template markup dynamically from an external resource, instead of using a static template.

Comment: That's the way to do it. Your template isn't worth anything if it's not compiled. @Sheldeeb